# O que é SSH e quais são suas vantagens sobre o HTTPS?

Tags: terminologia, https, ssh

Alguns serviços oferecem a conexão cliente-servidor através do SSH (Secure Shell). O que é esse SSH?

Um caso é o GitHub, que recomenda o SSH mesmo já oferecendo o HTTPS, porém o HTTPS me parece muito mais fácil e menos trabalhoso de conectar com o GitHub. Qual é a vantagem desse protocolo acima do HTTPS, se é que são comparáveis?

- [Connecting to GitHub with SSH](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sabe o prompt de comando windows ou o shell do linux? Então, são lugares onde você digita comandos a serem executados pelo computador/dispositivo ao qual você está conectado.

Quando você precisa se conectar com um servidor remoto, é preciso que os comandos, bem como quaisquer informações obtidas como resultado desses sejam trafegados pela rede de forma segura com criptografia. É aí que entra o SSH. O SSH provê essa funcionalidade de prompt de comandos através da rede com criptografia. Como o git é executado por meio de vários comandos shell, então faz sentido que você comunique-se com servidores remotos git por meio do SSH.

No entanto, o protocolo padrão de comunicação na internet é o HTTP e a sua versão com segurança e critografia (HTTPS). Assim sendo, o git também disponibiliza a possibilidade de interagir-se com ele por esse meio.

Em especial, quando você está trabalhando com scripts por linha de comando, o SSH torna-se algo natural. Quando você está utilizando um navegador, o uso do HTTPS torna-se praticamente obrigatório. Para satisfazer a ambos os casos, o git oferece os dois.

Aliás, o significado de SSH é "*Secure Shell*", e no caso, "*Shell*" é o nome do prompr de comandos do linux, também chamado de SH.

Comment: Bem legal a dissertação. 

Comment: @dvd, como fez este 'joinha'?

Comment: @Dherik https://getemoji.com/ - Escolha o que você quer e então copie-e-cole. Também existem extensões específicas de navegadores que te dão teclados de emojis.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, valeu :D

Comment: @Dherik Exatamente como o VictorStafusa falou... basta achar em qualquer site esses emojis e copiar, deste que não seja uma imagem  Esse aqui eu peguei do WhatsApp Web

Comment: @Dherik É como se fosse um texto, vc arrasta o mouse sobre, seleciona e copia CTRL+C

Comment: @dvd Entendi, valeu! 